# How can I fake keycloack call to use in local development?

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak

My company uses Keycloak for authentication connected with LDAP and returning a user object filled with corporative data.
Yet in this period we are all working from home and in my daily work having to authenticate in my corporative server every time I reload the app, has proven to be an expensive overhead. Especially with intermittent internet connections.

How can I fake the Keycloak call and make keycloak.protect() work as it has succeeded?

I can install a Keyclock server in my machine, but I'd rather not do that because it would be another server running in it besides, vagrant VM, Postgres server, be server, and all the other things I leave open.
It would be best to make a mock call and return a fixed hard-coded object.

My project's app-init.ts is this:

```
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { KeycloakUser } from './shared/models/keycloakUser';
<...>

export function initializer(
    keycloak: KeycloakService,
    <...>
): () => Promise<any> {
    return (): Promise<any> => {
        return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
            <...>    
            await keycloak.init({
                config: environment.keycloakConfig,
                initOptions: {
                    onLoad: 'login-required',
                    // onLoad: 'check-sso',
                    checkLoginIframe: false
                },
                bearerExcludedUrls: [],
                loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false
            }).then((authenticated: boolean) => {
                if (!authenticated) return;
                keycloak.getKeycloakInstance()
                    .loadUserInfo()
                    .success(async (user: KeycloakUser) => {
                       // ...
                       // load authenticated user data
                       // ...
                    })    
            }).catch((err: any) => rej(err));
            res();
        });
    };
```

I just need one fixed logged user. But it has to return some fixed customized data with it. Something like this:

```
{ username: '111111111-11', name: 'Whatever Something de Paula',
  email: 'whatever@gmail.com', department: 'sales', employee_number: 7777777 }
```

**EDIT**

I tried to look at the idea of @BojanKogoj but AFAIU from Angular Interceptor page and other examples and tutorials, it has to be injected in a component. Keycloak initialization is called on app initialization, not in a component. Also Keycloak's return is not the direct return of init() method. It passes through other objects in the `.getKeycloakInstance().loadUserInfo().success()` sequence.
Or maybe it's just me that didn't fully understand it. If anyone can come with an example of an interceptor that can intercept the call and return the correct result, that could be a possibility.

**Edit2**

Just to complement that what I need is for the whole keycloak's system to work. Please notice that the `(user: KeycloakUser) => {` function is passed to `success` method of keycloak's internal system. As I said above, routes have a keycloak.protect() that must work. So it's not just a simple case of returning a promise with a user. The whole .getKeycloakInstance().loadUserInfo().success() chain has to be mocked. Or at least that's how I understand it.

**I included an answer with the solution I made based on @yurzui's answer**

Will wait a couple of days to award the bounty to see if someone can came up with an even better solution (which I doubt).

Comment: I'm not sure what you use in KeycloakService, but maybe you could use Interceptor? That way you could intercept API call and return mocked response

Comment: Didn't knew it. Seems interesting. Will take a look later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can leverage Angular environment(or even `process.env`) variable to switch between real and mock implementations.

Here is a simple example of how to do that:

**app-init.ts**

```
...
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export function initializer(
  keycloak: KeycloakService
): () => Promise<any> {

  function authenticate() {
    return keycloak
      .init({
        config: {} as any,
        initOptions: {onLoad: 'login-required', checkLoginIframe: false},
        bearerExcludedUrls: [],
        loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false
      })
      .then(authenticated => {
        return authenticated ? keycloak.getKeycloakInstance().loadUserInfo() : Promise.reject();
      });
  }

  // we use 'any' here so you don't have to define keyCloakUser in each environment    
  const { keyCloakUser } = environment as any; 

  return () => {
    return (keyCloakUser ? Promise.resolve(keyCloakUser) : authenticate()).then(user => {
      // ...
      // do whatever you want with user
      // ...
    });
  };
}
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  keyCloakUser: {
    username: '111111111-11',
    name: 'Whatever Something de Paula',
    email: 'whatever@gmail.com',
  }
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
};
```

### Update

If you want to mock `KeycloakService` on client side then you can tell  Angular dependency injection to handle that:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { KeycloakService, KeycloakAngularModule } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { MockedKeycloakService } from './mocked-keycloak.service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    KeycloakAngularModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: KeycloakService,
      useClass: environment.production ? KeycloakService : MockedKeycloakService
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializer,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**mocked-keycloak.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Injectable()
class MockedKeycloakService extends KeycloakService {
  init() {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }

  getKeycloakInstance() {
    return {
      loadUserInfo: () => {
        let callback;
        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
          callback({
            userName: 'name'
          });
        });
        return {
          success: (fn) => callback = fn
        };
      }
    } as any;
  }
}
```

Comment: What I want is not just to get keycloakUser. I want the whole keycloack's system to work. Please notice that the `(user: KeycloakUser) => {` function is passed to success method of keycloak's internal system. What you did was merely removing the keyloack log in dev environment returning a user, but the token isn't inserted so the backend return 403. There's keycloak.protect() on routes that must work.

Comment: `success` method is deprecated. As for protect method, you can use mocked version of KeycloakSevice or create a proxy method where you can decide which option to use: `keycloak.protect()` or do nothing

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I added an example of how you can mock `KeycloakService`

Comment: We're almost there.... :) I made it work locally. Mocked protect in the BE. But when I try to make it connect to the real server, authenticate() returns an object with the success function inside that I should be calling. I still haven't tried to mock the class. It's 3am here. I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Yes!!! I made it! :) I was able to mock the class correctly. It's perfect now. The application starts very fast and smoothly. Thanks!! That mean you probably won the bounty. I'll just way a couple more days to see if someone can came up with something even better (which I doubt).

Comment: Adding a test case to production code is a terrible idea IMO

Answer (score 5):

Although you explicitly state that you think that mocking is the best option, I suggest to reconsider it in favor of setting up local Keycloak instance using docker. It becomes easy when you provide a realm to bootstrap your environment. I've been using this approach with success for over 2 years of developing applications that work with Keycloak. This approach will let you "substitute calls to your corporate server" hence I post it here.

Assuming that you have docker & docker-compose installed, you'll need:

**1. docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:10.0.1
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /tmp/dev-realm.json
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./dev-realm.json:/tmp/dev-realm.json
```

**2. dev-realm.json** (exact content depend on required settings, this is the minimum that you've mentioned in your question)

```
{
  "id": "dev",
  "realm": "dev",
  "enabled": true,
  "clients": [
    {
      "clientId": "app",
      "enabled": true,
      "redirectUris": [
        "*"
      ],
      "bearerOnly": false,
      "consentRequired": false,
      "standardFlowEnabled": true,
      "implicitFlowEnabled": false,
      "directAccessGrantsEnabled": false,
      "secret": "mysecret",
      "publicClient": false,
      "protocol": "openid-connect",
      "fullScopeAllowed": false,
      "protocolMappers": [
        {
          "name": "department",
          "protocol": "openid-connect",
          "protocolMapper": "oidc-usermodel-attribute-mapper",
          "consentRequired": false,
          "config": {
            "user.attribute": "department",
            "id.token.claim": "true",
            "access.token.claim": "true",
            "claim.name": "department",
            "userinfo.token.claim": "true"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "employee_number",
          "protocol": "openid-connect",
          "protocolMapper": "oidc-usermodel-attribute-mapper",
          "consentRequired": false,
          "config": {
            "user.attribute": "employee_number",
            "id.token.claim": "true",
            "access.token.claim": "true",
            "claim.name": "employee_number",
            "userinfo.token.claim": "true"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "111111111-11",
      "enabled": true,
      "firstName": "Whatever Something de Paula",
      "email": "whatever@gmail.com",
      "credentials": [{
        "type": "password",
        "value": "demo"
      }],
      "attributes": {
        "department": "sales",
        "employee_number": 7777777
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**3. Create dedicated Angular environment that will use the "http://localhost:8080/auth" and realm "dev" for your local development**

The advantages of this approach over mocking:

- all OIDC and keycloak features are working. I admit that it depends if you need them but you are free to use realm/client roles, groups, 'real' OIDC flow with token refreshal. This gives you guarantee that your local setup will work also with corporate service
- this setup can be stored in repository (contrary to manual setup of Keycloak server) and used both for working on web applications and backend services

By default, Keycloak uses a H2 in-memory database and needs about 600MB of RAM so I'd argue that it is a relatively low footprint.

Comment: Seems interesting... I'll give it a try. do you recommend any particular docker image ? This one is ok ? https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak

Comment: Yes, the one that you've linked is ok (it's the same that I've used in docker-compose file). It is the official docker image maintained by the Keycloak team so it should be all that you need to get started. Please remember to pick the same version of keycloak as you use in corporate environment.

Comment: As I comment in @yurzui answer I'll probably stick with mocking the class, as it has the lowest footprint and I was able to make it function very efficiently. But I will also try your solution in the next couple days and let you know the results.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

I was able to mock Keycloak service using the method @yurzui suggested. I'll document it here as it may be useful for somebody.

Initially I had posted a solution where I conditionally exported the mock  or real classes from the mock module. All worked well on dev mode, but when I tried to build the application for publishing in production server I got an error, so I had to return to the 2 class solution. I explain the problem in details [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029756/how-can-i-use-a-class-that-conditionally-exports-different-types-in-angular-app) question .

This is the working code (so far).

*Frontend:*

With a little help from @kev's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029756/how-can-i-use-a-class-that-conditionally-exports-different-types-in-angular-app) question and @yurzui (again :D) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029756/how-can-i-use-a-class-that-use-conditional-export-in-angulars-app-module) one, I created a MockKeycloakService class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export default class MockKeycloakService { 

    init() {
        console.log('[KEYCLOAK] Mocked Keycloak call');
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }

    getKeycloakInstance() {
        return {
            loadUserInfo: () => {
                let callback : any;
                Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                    callback({
                        username: '77363698953',
                        NOME: 'Nelson Teixeira',
                        FOTO: 'assets/usuarios/nelson.jpg',
                        LOTACAOCOMPLETA: 'DIOPE/SUPOP/OPSRL/OPSMC (local)',
                    });
                });
                return { success: fn=>callback = fn };
            }
        } as any;
    }

    login() {}  
    logout() {}
} 

const KeycloakServiceImpl =
  environment.production ? KeycloakService : MockKeycloakService

export { KeycloakServiceImpl, KeycloakService, MockKeycloakService };
```

then I substituted it in app.module:

```
<...>
import { KeycloakAngularModule } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { KeycloakServiceImpl } from 'src/app/shared/services/keycloak-mock.service';
import { initializer } from './app-init';
<...>

    imports: [
        KeycloakAngularModule,
         <...>  
    ],
    providers: [
        <...>,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializer,
            multi: true,
            deps: [KeycloakServiceImpl, <...>]
        },
        <...>
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then changed the type of keycloak service variable in app-init, that was the only change, but then I could remove KeycloackService import as it's being provided in app.module:

```
import { KeycloakUser } from './shared/models/keycloakUser';
<...>

export function initializer(
    keycloakService: any,
    <...>
): () => Promise<any> {
    return (): Promise<any> => {
        return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
            <...>    
            await keycloak.init({
                config: environment.keycloakConfig,
                initOptions: {
                    onLoad: 'login-required',
                    // onLoad: 'check-sso',
                    checkLoginIframe: false
                },
                bearerExcludedUrls: [],
                loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false
            }).then((authenticated: boolean) => {
                if (!authenticated) return;
                keycloak.getKeycloakInstance()
                    .loadUserInfo()
                    .success(async (user: KeycloakUser) => {

                        <...>

                    })    
            }).catch((err: any) => rej(err));
            res();
        });
    };
```

But in the component I still have to check which environment I'm on and instance the class correctly:

```
<...>
import { MockKeycloakService } from '../../shared/services/keycloak.mock.service';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';    
<...>

export class MainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    <...>
    keycloak: any;

    constructor(
        <...>           
    ) {
        this.keycloak = (environment.production) ? KeycloakServiceImpl : new KeycloakServiceImpl();
  }

    async doLogout() {
        await this.keycloak.logout();
    }

    async doLogin() {
        await this.keycloak.login();
    }
    <...>    
}
```

*Backend:*

That was easier, again I created a KeycloakMock class:

```
import KeyCloack from 'keycloak-connect';

class KeycloakMock {

    constructor(store, config) {
        //ignore them
    }

    middleware() {
        return (req, res, next) =>{ 
        next();
    }}

    protect(req, res, next) {
        return (req, res, next) =>{ 
        next();
    }}
}

const exportKeycloak = 
    (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'local') ? KeycloakMock : KeyCloack;

export default exportKeycloak;
```

Then I just substitued 'keycloak-connect' import on app.js by this class, and everythig worked fine. It connects to the real service if I set production = true and it mocks it with production = false.

Very cool solution. If anyone has anything to say on my implementation of @yurzui idea I'll like to hear from you.

Some notes:

- I still couln't get rid of having to check the environment in the main-component class, as if I do this in the mock class module:

  ```
  const KeycloakServiceImpl = 
      environment.production ? KeycloakService : new MockKeycloakService()
  ```

  app.module doesn't work anymore. and if I do this in main-component:

  ```
  constructor(
          <...>
          keycloakService: KeyclockServiceImpl;
      ) {  }
  ```

  The build fails with a "KeyclockServiceImpl refers to a value but is being used as a type here";
- I had to export all classes or the build fails

  ```
  export { KeycloakServiceImpl, KeycloakService, MockKeycloakService };
  ```